# How to close/kill SSH connection when bash shell exits?

Tags: bash, shell, bashrc

We are writing an application. As a part of it, we have to provide SSH access to each clients. In this process, we are providing SSH access to the client using a web UI. This ssh session is invoked from root user with some parameters, in such a way that the user shell is restricted to specific user permissions.

When the user exits the bash shell, it returns back to the root user. I want to terminate the ssh session when user exits the bash shell. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The SSH session will automatically close when the process that is started by the SSH server terminates.

If you have a script that prepares the session for the user, just call that with `ssh -t server user-script`. The option `-t` requests a terminal, that means the calling SSH client should have access to a terminal, unless terminal access doesn't matter for your client. In the last line of your script, use `bash` or a little more efficiently `exec bash`. As soon as that `bash` terminates, the SSH session will be terminated.